# IVR Framework to collect feedback

Tags: .net, voip, voice, phone-call, ivr

I want to write an application which will call the users , ask them some rating type questions. The user will rate on a scale of 1 to 7.
The users feedback will be saved in database.

I want to write this application in .NET.
Is there any framework which will help me develop this application?

Answer (score 1):

You can build an IVR on a cloud based communication platform like Twilio. 
Since you are using .NET env , you can use Twilio's C# helper libraries and Twilio Programmable Voice to build your IVR App.

Flow would be 
    (1) From your server make a POST call to the number you want to dial 
    (2) Once the call is answered respond with TwiML   for your IVR instructions ( text to speech)
    (3) Get user response using TwiML  and pass it your webhook to take further action ( store it or create further survey questions)

Here's a tutorial you can follow https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/csharp/mvc

Comment: Hey @abhijitMehta, thanks for sharing the Twilio community! Can we send you a shirt to say thanks? Email mspeir@twilio.com for details.